# How to create folder with the name contains forward slash / in documents directory in iOS platform

Tags: objective-c, hfs+

How to create a folder with the name which contains forward slash / in iOS ? Currently , its creating nested folder if a folder name contains forward slash. I want to create a folder with the name contains forward slash.

Answer (score 2):

The OS APIs prevent you from creating files or directories containing a forward slash (`/`), since that is the path separator for directories in HFS+. Technically HFS+ file names can contain this character, but the OS APIs prevent you from actually creating such files.

I recommend figuring out some other naming convention for your directories that doesn't include forward slashes (replace them with another character, for instance), or else just create nested directories.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/326103/mac-os-x-lion-what-are-invalid-characters-for-a-file-name

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Stuart. I expected the same.